# jQuery Animate Sibling Elements After Middle Siblings Removal

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-animate

I'm currently working on an interface with dynamic add and remove file input boxes. Using jQuery I've been able to animate the visual appearance of the container element that holds all of the File Input boxes, and fade in the elements that are being added after the space has been added.

What is stumping me, is that if a File Input box is removed from the middle of the stack, the others after it snap into place after removal.

What I was wondering is if anyone has experience with how to animate the elements that exist after the removal of a middle element.

Approximated HTML:

```
<div class="fileFields">
    <!-- first example field group -->
    <div class="fileField">
        <span class="buttonBrowse"></span>
        <span class="fileName"></span>
        <span class="hiddenInput"><input name="file_0" type="file" /></span>
        <span class="buttonRemove"></span>
    </div>
    <!-- middle example field group -->
    <div class="fileField">
        <span class="buttonBrowse"></span>
        <span class="fileName"></span>
        <span class="hiddenInput"><input name="file_1" type="file" /></span>
        <span class="buttonRemove"></span>
    </div>
    <!-- last example field group -->
    <div class="fileField">
        <span class="buttonBrowse"></span>
        <span class="fileName"></span>
        <span class="hiddenInput"><input name="file_1" type="file" /></span>
        <span class="buttonRemove"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fileFieldControls">
    <span class="buttonAdd"></span>
</div>
```

So, for clarity, if you look at the inline comments with the HTML sample, what I'm expecting from the correct answer is the way to remove "middle example field group" and animate the re-positioning of "last example field group" and any other field groups that would be behind it.

Edit: jQuery code included

```
function buttonAddClick() {

    // Container...
    fileField = $('<div class="fileField"></div>');

    // Interior elements...
    fileField.append('<span class="buttonBrowse">'+svgButtons['browse']+'</span>');
    fileField.append('<span class="fileName"></span>');
    fileField.append('<span class="hiddenInput"><input name="" type="file" /></span>');
    fileField.append('<span class="buttonRemove">Remove</span>');

    // Actions...
    fileField.children('.buttonBrowse').on('click', function() {
        $(this).siblings('.hiddenInput').find('input[type=file]').trigger('click');
    });
    fileField.children('.hiddenInput').find('input[type=file]').on('change', function() {
        $(this).parent().siblings('.fileName').html($(this).val().split('\\').pop());
    });
    fileField.children('.buttonRemove').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {

            // This is where the question answer will likely go...

            $(this).remove();
            $('.fileFields').animate( { "height" : $('.fileFields').outerHeight() - 37 }, 500);
        });
    });

    // Animate the field adding...
    $('#groupFiles').animate( { "height" : $('#groupFiles').outerHeight() + 37 }, 500, function() {
        fileField.appendTo('.fileFields').hide().fadeIn(500);
    } );

}

// Add Button Actions...
$('.buttonAdd').on('click', buttonAddClick);
$('.buttonAdd').trigger('click');
```

Comment: could you post your jQuery code as well?

Comment: Updated to include jQuery code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the visibility to `hidden`, making the element invisible while still taking up space. Then animate the height to 0 and have a callback on completion which removes the element from the DOM.

In the following example, I'm hiding the middle `fileField`, since that's what you were asking about, but it wouldn't be hard to update this to make it work for any fileField.

```
$('#remove').on('click', function () {
    $('.fileField').eq(1).css('visibility', 'hidden').animate({
        height: 0
    }, 300, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });

});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/snHmv/)**

Comment: Would it be possible to fade the element out instead of snapping the visibility from shown to hidden? I've got it working without .fadeOut, but it seems a faded object no longer has height.

Comment: Found the answer, opacity can be animated. Accepted solution.